# How does npm version work?

Tags: git, npm, npm-version

I'm a little hazy on how [`npm version`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version) works. The documentation says:

> If run in a git repo, it will also create a version commit and tag.

Does that mean I don't have to run `git commit` or `git tag` or does it just take the place of `git tag -a <version>`? If I did something like this would I be creating a double commit?

```
git add . -A
git commit -m "<commit message>"
git push origin master
npm version <patch|minor|major> -m "<version description>" ## instead of git tag -a <version> ##
git push --tags
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your understanding is mostly correct

When you execute the `npm version` command the following is done:

1. bump package version as directed in `package.json`
2. create a commit containing only the update to `package.json` with the message specified when invoking `npm version`.
3. create a git tag

You can then execute `npm publish` to publish to the npm registry, and git push your tag to your remote repository when you see fit

---

### The long answer

As for the exact commands that our executed as you expressed interest in this via comments:

adding the files to staging:

```
git add /path/to/package.json
```

[See source](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/656bce7dd0f9753a273912e803261ed246593924/lib/version.js#L328).

*If lock and shrinkwrap package files are also present they are also added as above!*

creation of the commit:

```
git commit -m {version message}
```

[See source](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/656bce7dd0f9753a273912e803261ed246593924/lib/version.js#L299).

as for creation of the tag:

```
git tag {version no.} -am {version message}
```

or if signing is turned on:

```
git tag {version no.} -sm {version message}
```

[See source](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/656bce7dd0f9753a273912e803261ed246593924/lib/version.js#L310).

For reference the `version message` is optional, if it is excluded from the CLI input then it will default to have the value of `version no.`.

Comment: I'm more interested in how it interacts with git. what git commands does it perform for you?

Comment: @jwerrre I've now added these to my answer

Comment: While it may be obvious to most people, I'd explicitly mention that any file added to staging with `git add .` before running `npm version {version_type} -m {version message}` is also added to the commit.